# what is the purpose of tensorflow::port::InitMain?

Tags: tensorflow

There's not much documentation on `InitMain`, although the examples call it from their main() routines.

The implementations at `tensorflow/tensorflow/core/platform/posix/port.cc` and `tensorflow/tensorflow/core/platform/windows/port.cc` are just empty functions.

Is this obsolete?  Or a placeholder for the future?  If the code that integrates TensorFlow is a library itself, can the call to InitMain be skipped, or should it be called with dummy params?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `tensorflow::port::InitMain()` function is a placeholder that is important when supporting execution environments where a particular function must be called before execution starts. As a similar example, when you run an MPI job, you must call [`MPI_Init()`](https://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.1/www3/MPI_Init.html) before using any of MPI-related functionality.

If your program does not need to run on such an environment (such as the default POSIX platform), you can currently safely ignore it.